# Is there a solution to JDBC driver bug in "Out Of Band Breaks"?

Tags: jdbc, oracle-sqldeveloper

There is a long standing issue with SQL Developer disconnecting when used over VPN and other less than perfect networks.

As per a member from SQL Developer Team, it's a known bug in JDBC driver, unable to cope with 'Out Of Band Breaks'.
He also proposes setting **AddVMOption -Doracle.net.disableOob=true** as a workaround.
See more at:
[OTN Discussion Forums: SQL Developer: Not able to view tables](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2202388&start=15&tstart=0)

I want to ask, if anyone is aware of this bug being solved, or have a better solution than proposed above?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

setting java system property `oracle.net.disableOob=true` is not a bad solution, this is common misunderstanding. Oracle just fallbacks to polling mechanism, server process will permanently check if there is cancel message sent by client even when query is running.
There is no more bug in `JDBC driver` (at least not in `11.2.0.3`), the main reason why it does not work is the following. When connecting to oracle DB through VPN, there is for sure some Firewall. And most modern firewalls are clearing `URG` packets for many security reasons. They do not drop packets with `URG` flags, just clear those bits.

Even in `RFC` there is written that `URG` packets are not correctly implemented on several platforms.

There is a possibility to persuade security officer to allow `URG` flags, but will be hard work with them, I'm affraid.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very old question but @PavolBabel's answer above led me to a solution for `SQL*Plus`, `sqlcl`, and `cx_Oracle` on MacOS Big Sur so I'm hoping the this advice will help someone else.

I was getting `ORA-12571: TNS:packet writer failure` on Big Sur and not all of those apps support the `-DdisableOob=true` java directive (namely `cx_Oracle`).

I added `DISABLE_OOB=on` to my `$TNS_ADMIN/sqlnet.ora` file, per [Oracle's documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e10835/sqlnet.htm#NETRF185) and it fixed SQL Developer's constant disconnecting whilst on a VPN; and fixed SQL*Plus, sqlcl, and cx_Oracle's inability to connect *at all* (`ORA-12571`) on Mac OS Big Sur, all in one "swell foop" as my grandmother used to say.

Comment: Do you have the latest versions?  Oracle 19 has automatic OOB detection so I haven't needed to set DISABLE_OOB on my Mac for a long time.  You'll need 19+ Instant Client together with DB 19+.

Comment: @ChristopherJones Yes, I have 19.8 across the board on a 2019 MBP w/ Big Sur. I can't connect at all without OOB disabled. I assume it's one of my company's firewall/ASA/antivirus settings causing it and not the fault of Oracle.

Comment: All SSL based VPNs(Zscaller, Cisco, OpenVPN) have this problem. They wrap TCP stream into another TCP stream, and when upwrapping OOB flag is discarded from TCP header.

Answer (score 0):

OCI Thick clients are able to use sqlnet.ora DISABLE_OOB=on for sure. To be honest I am not sure about JDBC Thin client, if it follows that sqlnet.ora parameter.
Thing with MAC OS surprises me. I am on Monterey (12.6.6) and it seems 19c really has aoutomatic OOB detection and it seems OOB has not been implemented on MAC. I have perform tcpdump and truss (strace on Linux) and all my client sessions stick back to old polling mechanism for sending break packets (even with DISABLE_OOB=FALSE).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: OK, now I have tested on LINUX.
- sqlnet.ora => DISABLE_OOB=TRUE works only for OCI THICK CLIENT (sqlplus, also SQL Developer/SQLcl but only when configured to use thick client).
- java option -Doracle.net.disableOob=true works for JDBC Thin (usually pepole use SQLcl and SQLDeveloper with Thin driver).